# RxJS verify existence of result

Tags: rxjs

From design and overall code quality, what detection of result existence in array that fulfill some criteria would you recommend? Assuming, that empty array may be queried as well and we want to have access to all elements fulfilling criteria at once, does following code seems reliable?

Additional trivia:
* Code is handling HTTP requests, so it's a guarantee this observable will finish

```
Rx.Observable.from([] /*or [1,2,3], or [1,2,50]*/)
.filter(v => v > 20)
.toArray()
.filter(a => a.length > 0)
.defaultIfEmpty([])
.subscribe(v => {
  if (v.length === 0) {console.log('no results')}
  else { console.log('Results present', v) }
}, (e) => {console.log(e)}, () => {console.log('done')})
```

-- EDIT --
Second call to `filter` is necessary, because empty array `[]` successfully can bypass `defaultIfEmpty` operator

Comment: Why dont you just remove the second filter and the defaultIfEmpty?

Comment: This approach makes sense if you know for sure that the source Observable sooner or later completes completes AND if it emits its events asynchronously. If the source Observable emits only once the entire Array, then you better filter the Array.

Comment: @Picci Does the `filter` operator handle whole array and other iterable objects by itself? Or shall I in my predicate implement some `forEach`?
@TamasHegedus Oh why don't you post it as answer? :) I'd be happy to upvote

Comment: What I want to say is the following. If you have a source Observable that emits, for example every 100 milliseconds, a value and you know for sure that it will complete after a certain number of emissions, then your approach of `filter` (just one `filter` as @madjaoue suggests) and then `toArray` works. If the source Observable emits only **once** an Array, then you should just use the `filter` method of Array within a `map` operator of Observable. If this is not clear, I can give more details with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify cour code : `toArray` returns an empty list when the observable finishes, even if no element is received.

```
Rx.Observable.from([] /*or [1,2,3], or [1,2,50]*/)
.filter(v => v > 20)
.toArray() // will return [] when the observable finishes and filter discards all your elements 
.subscribe(v => {
  if (v.length === 0) {console.log('no results')}
  else { console.log('Results present', v) }
  }, (e) => {console.log(e)}, () => {console.log('done')}
)
```

Comment: This makes prefect sense!